# Adding laravel blade content in adminLTE

Tags: laravel, laravel-vue

I have a problem attaching blade content in the adminLTE dashboard starter package. I am also using vue js components and they are displayed well using router-link. Am managing users with pure laravel without vue Js and I want to include that blade in the same dashboard. Is this possible?
my code:

```
           <li class="nav-item">
            <router-link to="/customer" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-user text-orange"></i>
              <p>
                Locations
              </p>
            </router-link>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-cog text-green"></i>
              <p>
                Management
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="{{route('usertab')}}" class="nav-link">// I want to include it here
                  <i class="fas fa-users  nav-icon text-teal "></i>
                  <p>Usersx</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              </ul>
```

I have added this to content section.

```
 <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
   <router-view></router-view>
   @if(Request::is('/usertab'))  //but this is not working 
   @yield('content')
   @endif
  </div>
</div>
```

My router link
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

```
let routes = [
  { path: '/userbio', component: require('./components/UserBioComponent.vue').default},
  { path: '/users', component: require('./components/UsersComponent.vue').default},
  { path: '/customer', component: require('./components/LocationComponent.vue').default},
]
```

and my blade web route

```
Route::get('usertab','AdminController@getuserall')->name('usertab');
```

Any idea to this

Comment: can you specify which github repo you are using for adminLTE, adminLTE are available for different languages, even same language can have many adminLTE repos in github

Comment: @bhucho  https://adminlte.io/themes/v3/starter.html#